# Multiple Inner HTML in a few lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piano with 88 keys.
"keys" are the event key "k" .
I use handlebars and backbone so it is impossible to write thousands of lines here..

What I would like is, if there is any way to write the following code in fewer lines .. (I use Javascript and jQuery so both are ok)
Thank you very much

```js
if (document.getElementById('do').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "C"; 
}

if (document.getElementById('re').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "D"; 
}    

if (document.getElementById('mi').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "E"; 
} 
if (document.getElementById('fa').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "F"; 
}    

if (document.getElementById('sol').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "G"; 
}
if (document.getElementById('la').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "A"; 
}    

if (document.getElementById('si').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "B"; 
} 
if (document.getElementById('do2').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "C"; 
}    

if (document.getElementById('re2').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "D"; 
}

if (document.getElementById('mi').innerHTML) {
document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = "E"; 
}
```

Comment: What are "keys" in `document.getElementById(keys)` ? Can you be more specific on what trying to achieve here?

Comment: `document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = Object.entries({ do : 'C', re: 'D', me: 'E', fa: 'F', sol: 'G', la: 'A', si: 'B', do2: 'C', re2: 'D', me2: 'E' }).filter(([s, k]) => document.getElementById(s).innerHTML).map(([s, k]) => k).join('');`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lookup of your mapping and using iterate through each pair of key and value check for condition and assign it to html.

```
const lookup = {do: 'C', re: 'D', mi: 'E', fa: 'F', sol: 'G', la: 'A', si: 'B', do2: 'C', re2: 'D'}
Object.entries(lookup).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  if (document.getElementById(key).innerHTML) {
    document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = value; 
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks, I will test it now

Comment: It works fine with 88 keys, if it was only sharps or flats... so now the problem is that one black key (one id ie doSharp) has 2 innerHTML, so it does not understand which of the two Inner HTML have to choose .. Do Sharp or Re Flat ... for example <div id="do" class="white"></div>\ <div id="doSharp" class="black"></div>\<div id="re" class="white"></div>\  .... Any idea? thanks..

Comment: Can you share the current and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can with variable

```
const constVar = document.getElementById(keys);
if (document.getElementById('do').innerHTML)
{ constVar.innerHTML = "C"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact use case, but this code can be optimized by a map and for-loop. The sample code is below.

Sample approach below:

```
const KEY_MAP = {
  "do": "C",
  "re": "D",
  "mi": "E",
  "fa": "F",
  "sol": "G",
  "la": "A",
  "si": "B",
  "do2": "C",
  "re2": "D",
}

function updateDomLabelUsingKeyMap(keys) {
  Object.keys(KEY_MAP).forEach(el => {
    if (document.getElementById(el).innerHTML) {
      document.getElementById(keys).innerHTML = KEY_MAP[el]; 
    }
  }); 
}
```

Call this `updateDomLabelUsingKeyMap` function with the keys prop.